# Is MonoDroid worth the effort?

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android

Having finished and successfully published my very first iPhone app with MonoTouch, I'm now seeking for the Android version of the same app.

MonoTouch was very helpful for me, since I still think Objective C is insane to read and write (especially on German keyboards). So C# was a good alternative here.

On Android Java is the primary development language, from what I know. Since Java is much closer to C# than Objective C is, I'm in doubt whether I really should add the extra "layer" of MonoDroid or just use plain Java.

**My question is:**

From your experiences, was it worth the effort to use MonoDroid or would you do your next project directly with Java?

**Update 1:**

After a hint from @Dani I found out that there is already a [similar question and an answer over at p.se.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33076/as-a-c-developer-would-you-learn-java-to-develop-for-android-or-use-monodroid-i). Should I delete or close this question or ask an admin to do?

Comment: I personally write everything in C++ and write simple wrappers for the UI, but that mainly because what I do is more algorithmic apps.

Comment: "Vote to close": I was pretty sure I get votes to close :-) Can you suggest another way to ask the question and/or another SE site to ask? (http://android.stackexchange.com/ says they don't take programming questions).

Comment: What about http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your developing the same app for Monodroid, then it would probably make sense, as you should be able to use a large majority of your existing code, and just re-write the UI layer, as well as any platform specific code.

Comment: This is not necessarily true: I am currently developing MonoDroid app for my employer. My teammate is working on the MonoTouch version simultaneously. We thought we would be able to share code and just separate the UI. Unfortunately things like fetching dynamic resources, application flow, Intent Filtering and more are so platform-specific that it wasn't practical. I agree with the answer but not the justification, based on my experience :) I blogged on this exact subject here: http://syndicatex.com/programming/mono-for-android-tips/

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps it would be still possible given a bit of detailed planning of both projects. For example, I've written a library for my iPhone app in monotouch for the network layer, and a lot of custom classes for transferring data, etc... I have designed it so I can use the same library on my server running .NET Not only will this save me time, but it will ensure the code processing data at either end of the pipe (iphone <====> server) is exactly the same. I agree with you that there is potential for many gotchas. Its best to keep stuff very generic in shared libaries like this.

Comment: I think it's definitely possible. It just wasn't practical for us because the abstraction required to keep it that generic outweighed the benefit of sharing code. I just mentioned it because it was a call we had to make once we got a better understanding of the platforms. We're still learning though!

Answer (score 1):

Recently I also interested in this question and wrote [this article](http://www.yumasoft.com/node/122). It reveals almost all the pros and cons that I encountered while developing my first MonoDroid application.